# Question and answer over multiple csv files in langchain

Tags: python, python-3.x, langchain

I've a folder with multiple csv files, I'm trying to figure out a way to load them all into langchain and ask questions over all of them.

Here's what I have so far.

```
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain import OpenAI, VectorDBQA
from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader
from langchain.document_loaders.csv_loader import CSVLoader
import magic
import os
import nltk

os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = '...'

loader = DirectoryLoader('../data/', glob='**/*.csv', loader_cls=CSVLoader)

documents = loader.load()

text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=400, chunk_overlap=0)

texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'])

docsearch = Chroma.from_documents(texts, embeddings)

qa = VectorDBQA.from_chain_type(llm=OpenAI(), chain_type="stuff", vectorstore=docsearch)

query = "how many females are present?"
qa.run(query)
```

Comment: is there a chance you finished up with something?

Comment: Did you find any solution on this. I am able to do the embedding the multiple files but the answers are not correct. How did you solve it.

Comment: [PrivateDocBot](https://github.com/Abhi5h3k/PrivateDocBot)

Created using langchain and chainlit 

It also streams using langchain just like ChatGpt it displays word by word and works locally on PDF data. ‍ 

code reference.

Answer (score 2):

You should load them all into a vectorstore such as `Pinecone` or `Metal`. Then use a `RetrievalQAChain` or `ConversationalRetrievalChain` depending on if you want memory or not.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether you want to integrate multiple csv files for your query or compare among them. Here is the link if you want to compare/see the differences among multiple csv files using similar approach with querying one file. https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/agents/toolkits/examples/csv.html

```
agent = create_csv_agent(OpenAI(temperature=0), ['titanic.csv', 'titanic_age_fillna.csv'], verbose=True)
agent.run("how many rows in the age column are different?")
```

[screenshot for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTgLJ.png)

Comment: What version of LangChain is that? with the last version I get an error when passing a list of files.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using open source local LLM like llama2 for this purpose. Try `localGPT`. https://github.com/PromtEngineer/localGPT